# Does CPython optimize the creation of constant sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple function that creates a set for faster lookups. The function will be used a lot. Now, it also takes time to create a set, but this set is fixed for the lifetime of the program; should I lift its creation so that it is only created once, or can I expect Python to know to do as much without my interference?

Example: Is it ok to write the function below, or should the definition of `drop_chars` be lifted outside the function so that it's only executed once?

```
def strip_by_category(word):
    drop_chars = set("abcdefg")
    return "".join(c for c in word if c not in drop_chars)
```

**Edit:** Since I was asked to be fully explicit, the "lifted" alternative would be as follows; please put aside the small performance hit from dereferencing a non-global variable, it's really not what the qustion is about (and I'm not after that kind of micro-optimization anyway.)

```
drop_chars = set("abcdefg")

def strip_by_category(word):
    return "".join(c for c in word if c not in drop_chars)
```

#### Notes

1. Yes, I know I should use `str.translate` instead for *this* example. It's a placeholder to show the use of the constant set.
2. I am asking about the latest and greatest version of Python. Historical versions may differ, that's ok.

Comment: I see the example of "lifting creation," but where's the example of the alternative so we can compare actual code?

Comment: Also note that you can easily time various code snippets with the `timeit` module, so these "which one is faster" questions are largely moot.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The questions are not moot, a decent benchmark with `timeit` over some varied datasets *is* a valid answer of course

Comment: Sure, I can profile my code, and (with a little help) I could find out what kind of byte code it produces for *this* function. But I would like to know what I can expect, more generally, in terms of optimising this kind of constructs.

Comment: Still no example of the alternative? I can't even tell whether the posted example is the "fast" one in terms of the function itself (assuming the "slow" one would be `...if c not in set('abcdefg')`) or the "slow" one (assuming this function is called many times).

Comment: @Tigerhawk, this is the "slow" version because the set definition (based on the answer I accepted) will be executed every time the function runs. The alternative is to place the line `drop_chars = set("abcdefg")` outside the function definition -- plus a local alias if we're worried about the cost of the name lookup. I didn't think it's so obsure, sorry.

Comment: Also drawing on the accepted answer, writing `...if c not in { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }` is faster, not slower, than the version in the question -- since it can be optimised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython doesn't use constants when function calls are involved, because you can always override `set` to point to a different function. [Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) started supporting `LOAD_CONST` when a  set literal is used in `in` conditions, but still not for assignments.

If you only want to create the set once, you can turn it to a default argument and use `frozenset` instead to prevent unwanted mutations.

```
def strip_by_category(word, drop_chars=frozenset("abcdefg")):
    return "".join(c for c in word if c not in drop_chars)
```

Comment: to illustrate this builds the set once prior to function call you could add `print(strip_by_category.__defaults__)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer-- I'd forgotten the pesky redefinition factor! But are you saying that if I write `if not in set(...)`, the set could be lifted out and created only once, provided the `...` is immutable? Can the argument be a tuple, or will only a literal be recognized as sufficiently reliable?

Comment: And thanks for the default argument suggestion; it does keep the definition closer, in terms of code logic, than defining it at the module level. But it is not really a sensible argument for my function... I might define it at the module level or live with the inefficiency.

Comment: @alexis No, like I said Python can't optimize anything related to a function call(for eg. `set()`) in any case, because user can always override these names. It's only applicable when we use a literal like `if 'a' not in {1, 2, 3}`. This is also applicable to list and tuple literals.

Comment: @alexis Yes global variable is also fine, but global lookup is slow compared to a local variable, I suggested it for the same reason.

Comment: Right, a _set literal_, got it now. Thanks.